# HTTP Client Android Studio

Tags: rest, android-studio, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

When I'm using IntelliJ Ultimate I often find myself using the built in HTTP Client plugin.

This plugin allows you to organize your REST endpoints in a plain text file ending with `.http`, which is really handy for sharing them with the team over GIT.
It also allows you to easily execute them from your IDEA.

For Example

[image]

I noticed that Android Studio does not have this plugin.
I tried looking for it in the `plugins` section, but I was unable to find it.

Does anybody know how I can enable it anyway?

Btw I'm using Android Studio 3.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use [HTTP Client](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/http-client-in-product-code-editor.html) in Android Studio, because this feature is only available for the Ultimate edition. But you can use IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate for android development, because it supports almost all the features from Android Studio.

From [Android Studio and IntelliJ IDEA FAQ](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/05/intellij-idea-and-android-studio-faq/):

> Q: If I rely on features that are only available in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate (such as additional version control plugins), will I be able to use Android Studio?
>
> A: No, these additional features will not be available in Android Studio. You should continue using IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate.

Comment: do you have/know alternative HTTP Client for Intellij CE ?